# Print invoice and redirect back to page in JSF page

Tags: jsf, paypal, paypal-sandbox, jsf-2.2, paypal-rest-sdk

I created this simple example of PayPal express checkout with JSF:

**xhtml:**

```
<h:form target="_blank">
    <h:commandButton value="paypal" action="#{pricingCalculator.initPayPal}" image="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"/>
</h:form>
```

**Java code:**

```
public void initPayPal() throws SSLConfigurationException, InvalidCredentialException, IOException, HttpErrorException, InvalidResponseDataException, ClientActionRequiredException, MissingCredentialException, InterruptedException, OAuthException, ParserConfigurationException, com.paypal.exception.SSLConfigurationException, com.paypal.exception.InvalidCredentialException, com.paypal.exception.HttpErrorException, com.paypal.exception.InvalidResponseDataException, com.paypal.exception.ClientActionRequiredException, com.paypal.exception.MissingCredentialException, com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.OAuthException, org.xml.sax.SAXException
    {
        PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
        paymentDetails.setPaymentAction(PaymentActionCodeType.fromValue("Sale"));
        PaymentDetailsItemType item = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
        BasicAmountType amt = new BasicAmountType();
        amt.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromValue("USD"));
        double itemAmount = 1.00;
        amt.setValue(String.valueOf(itemAmount));
        int itemQuantity = 1;
        item.setQuantity(itemQuantity);
        item.setName("item");
        item.setAmount(amt);

        List<PaymentDetailsItemType> lineItems = new ArrayList<PaymentDetailsItemType>();
        lineItems.add(item);
        paymentDetails.setPaymentDetailsItem(lineItems);
        BasicAmountType orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
        orderTotal.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromValue("USD"));
        orderTotal.setValue(String.valueOf(itemAmount * itemQuantity));
        paymentDetails.setOrderTotal(orderTotal);
        List<PaymentDetailsType> paymentDetailsList = new ArrayList<PaymentDetailsType>();
        paymentDetailsList.add(paymentDetails);

        SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
        setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setReturnURL("http://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/java?success=true");
        setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setCancelURL("http://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/java?cancel=true");

        setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setPaymentDetails(paymentDetailsList);

        SetExpressCheckoutRequestType setExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType(setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails);
        setExpressCheckoutRequest.setVersion("104.0");

        SetExpressCheckoutReq setExpressCheckoutReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
        setExpressCheckoutReq.setSetExpressCheckoutRequest(setExpressCheckoutRequest);

        Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
        sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");
        sdkConfig.put("acct1.UserName", "peter.penzov_api1.gmail.com");
        sdkConfig.put("acct1.Password", "5LQB5QHQJVKP9QKN");
        sdkConfig.put("acct1.Signature", "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A6JqBNQNOE3.Jwxfs7nIV1jR7qcl");
        PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);
        SetExpressCheckoutResponseType setExpressCheckoutResponse = service.setExpressCheckout(setExpressCheckoutReq);

        String token = setExpressCheckoutResponse.getToken();

        String link = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=" + token;

        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        externalContext.redirect(link);
    }
```

I can successfully perform payment but when I click pay button I'm redirected to `http://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/java?success=true` I would like to print Paypal invoice? What Java code I need to add?

After I perform successfully payment I want to be redirected back to JSF page but with old data. How I can save the old data? Maybe I have to use Session scope bean?

Comment: Yes, use session bean or viewescoped. All ain basic jsf stuff, not paypal related. Just like the paypal question part is not jsf related. Please focus your questions (= besides knowing what it is,about, also one question per question)

Answer (score 0):

In the SetExpressCheckout, just change the return URL to your own return URL and you should be good to go.